# Statistics: Probability

Tags: probability

A bag contains 4 red marbles, 3 black marbles and 3 blue marbles. Three marbles are drawn at random without replacing from the bag. What is the probability that the marbles contain exactly one red marble?

Comment: Welcome to MSE! Here, we are generally glad to help *provided* the question shows effort. For instance, you might have looked up some source but couldn't quite understand it, or you might have partially solved it but got stuck somewhere. Show us what you've tried, and we'll be better suited to help you out!

Comment: Are you familiar at all with the [Hypergeometric Distribution](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hypergeometric_distribution)?

Comment: No, I was not taught that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a way of doing it without using binomial coefficients.

Notice that if we pick $3$ marbles, and we want the probability that exactly one of them is red, then we have either the red marble is the first marble picked, it is the second marble picked, or it is the third marble picked.

Let's start by assuming the red marble was the first one picked and the other two were not red. The probability of this happening is $$\frac{4}{10}*\frac{6}{9} * \frac{5}{8}$$
*Can you see why this is the case?*

Then you need to do this again, but now let's assume the red marble was picked second. The probability of this is $$\frac{6}{10} * \frac{4}{9} * \frac58$$
*Again, do you see why?*

Then simply take the final case where the red marble is picked last.
$$\frac{6}{10} * \frac{5}{9} * \frac48$$

Our final answer would be the sum of these three values.

Comment: Oh nice that you got the same result, using an other method!

Comment: So why is it over 9 and 8?

Comment: Because we are picking without replacement. After picking the first ball, there is one less ball in total. Then after we pick the second one, there are now two less than what we started with.

Comment: Okay thank you ... the answer is 1/6 + 1/6 + 1/6 = 0.5

Comment: Correct :) $$ $$ $$

Comment: Um ... how did the 6 and 5 come about\??

Comment: If there's four reds that mean there are $6$ that are not red at the start. Then after we start picking.......

Answer (score 0):

Here are some hints. Look at it in terms of combinations. (It doesn't matter when the red marble shows up, so let's just grab three of them at once and call it a day. It's functionally the same as drawing three without replacement.)

1. How many ways can you choose one red marble?
2. How many ways can you choose two non-red marbles?
3. How many ways can you choose three marbles?

Can you take it from here?

Spoiler:

> You can pick a red marble $_4C_1 = 4$ ways. You can pick two non-red marbles $_6C_2 = 15$ ways. You can pick three marbles $_{10}C_3 = 120$ ways. So, the probability is $4\cdot 15/120 = 1/2$.

Comment: You can choose one red marble: 4/10 ... two non red marbles: 6/10 ... you can choose 3 marbles: 3/10 ...

Comment: Added the spoiler.

Answer (score 0):

I think it is $$\frac{\binom{4}{1}\binom{3}{2}\binom{3}{0}+\binom{4}{1}\binom{3}{1}\binom{3}{1}+\binom{4}{1}\binom{3}{0}\binom{3}{2}}{\binom{10}{3}}$$

Comment: You get a simpler expression if you simply separate the marbles into red and non-red.

Comment: A simplier expression is not even a better expression, but thanks for your hint!

Comment: It depends: "better" for what purpose?  It might be better for the purposes of explaining to the OP.  Anyway, just a thought!

Comment: I don't understand that equation

Comment: To take one marple of the four ones we get $$\binom{4}{1}$$ and so on

Comment: I tried working it out. This is what I did: P (Red) = 4/10 ... P (Not Red) = 6/10 ... Therefore the probability that all marbles are not red is (0.6)^4 = 0.1296 ... Therefore P ( At least one is red) = 1 - (0.6)^4 = 1 - 0.1296 = 0.8704

Comment: ok, i have got an other result, but anyway...

Comment: I think it is a hypergeometric distribution

Comment: What do you mean?

Comment: see here https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hypergeometric_distribution